# input validation via JMESpath in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, jmespath

So for example i have the following input:

```
<input type="text" name="field1" [(ngModel)]="rule['condition']">
```

in this input field is following input valid `saleschannel.totalamount > 15`. At the moment i test the validation with `jmespath.search({ } , rule['condition'])`.

So i have following code part

```
<input type="text" name="field1" [(ngModel)]="rule['condition']"
[class.valid]="jmespath.search({ } , rule['condition'])">
```

The Problem with this is, if my input is not valid cause of syntax error i get an console error. So for the `[class.invalid]="XXX"` i need a way to catch the error, which detects for me that the input is invalid.

**What can i do to achieve this or is there a better way than my attempt?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working along time ago but forgot to answer on my own question.

**component.html**

```
<input type="text" (ngModelChange)="ValidateJMES($event)" [class.valid]="isValid">
```

**component.ts**

```
public jmespath = require('../../assets/jmespath.js');
public valid: bool;

ValidateJMES(newValue){
    try {
        this.jmespath.search({ } , newValue);
        valid = true;

    } catch(e) {
        valid = false;
    }
}
```

This way you can check if an input is a valid jmespath search expression.